# Поиск элементов в javascript

Tags: javascript

Требуется проверить все поля ввода(input) на странице на наличие атрибута(вопросы: как найти все поля input На странице ?)
Как добавить после каждого поля (подчеркну ПОСЛЕ) элемент к примеру  с текстом именно на javascript чистом!

```
var datasetTest = document.getElementByName('test');

if(datasetTest.dataset) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div')
    newdiv.innerHTML = 'Новый элемент списка'
    datasetTest.parentNode.insertBefore(newdiv, datasetTest)
    datasetTest.beforeHTML = datasetTest.dataset.test;
}
```

Comment: А где ваша попытка решения вопроса?

Comment: Пытаюсь искать по имени так как не знаю как по полям, а метод getElementsByName не возвращает кол-во по этому не знаю как пройти вообще по циклу полный бред

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, этот код в текст вопроса. Вопросы можно (и иногда нужно) редактировать

Comment: метода в afterHTML тут так же нету( с jquery все проще но увы

Comment: getElementsByTagName - не оно ли?

Comment: и что я получу как обращатся в массиве к элементам?

Comment: Если вы не знаете как обращаться к элементам массива - читайте книжки по JS.

Comment: как добавить блок div к примеру после input

Comment: @LiePie По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

ну просто же все `inputElement.parentNode.insertBefore(newdiv, inputElement.nextSibling)` - это если `inputElement.nextSibling` есть, иначе просто добавляем в "родителя"

---

Ответ из комментария [@tutankhamun](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177613/).